# Spring Boot link to static content

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring boot app with a static and templates folder within the src/main/resources folder.  I am trying to link to a static page like:

```
<link href="../layout/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="../layout/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I have tried about everything I can think of to get it to work.  If i change it to

```
<link href="http://localhost:8080/layout/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="http://localhost:8080/layout/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

it works, but then it shows in my page source, and as always I want to hide my implementation from my users.  What is a way I can access this static content without hard coding my domain, and without using localhost?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring-boot looks up the static resouce by default under `src/main/resources/static/`

So if you dont have any folder structure after `static/` like `static/index.css` this should work:

```
<link href="/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But if you have a structure folder after `static/` like `static/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css` this should work:

```
<link href="/layout/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

So you just have to add the url after static in your link.

P.S.:

If you use `thymeleaf` as template engine you should also add the `th:href` tag to your link.

```
<link href="/layout/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" th:href="@/layout/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: I should have mentioned I have no issues running locally, it is when I push to my VPS servier.  I posted another question with more details at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50064927/spring-boot-static-content-works-fine-locally-but-not-when-i-push-to-vps-server.  Thanks for your help!