# Spring boot static content works fine locally but not when I push to VPS server

Tags: spring-boot, cpanel

I have a spring boot that runs fine locally and I have no problems accessing:  http://localhost:8080/staticlayouts/blah.html.  Whenever I upload to my VPS running Cpanel/WHM i get the following when I try to access http://www.example.com/staticlayouts/blah.html where example.com is my website.  I Have no issues accessing my main page, other than static content is not loading.  Any ideas what I need to change in WHM/Cpanel configuration to get the static content of spring boot to stop getting the following error:

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /staticlayouts/blah.html.

Reason: DNS lookup failure for: localhost:8080staticlayouts

Additionally, a 502 Bad Gateway error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of wasting my time trying worthless things, the problem was because of my apache httpd configuration.  In my vhost.config file I had this:

```
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080
```

I needed this (**notice the slashes on the urls**):

```
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

This url is a great reference: https://medium.com/@codebyamir/using-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-spring-boot-embedded-tomcat-f704da73e7c8